# Error in JSP in calling java class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have created a sample jsp file and a java class. i am calling a java class in jsp file. it is giving the error. "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: "
below is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        testClass tc = new testClass();
        tc.testMethod();
    %>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
```

java class

```
public class testClass {

public void testMethod(){
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
}
```

Comment: Is it all that compiler says? There must be some details.

Comment: Since the error message ends in ":", there is something else in it. Please examine the full output of the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import your java class in your JSP at the beginning. Like this-

```
<%@ page import="<your package structure here>.testClass"%>
```

before `<html>`.

Also close your `html` tag at the end. It seems unclosed.

Need to mention, your class name starts a with lowercase letter. Its a good practice to give your class, a name starting with upper case letter.

Comment: my mistake. thnx. it is working fine in netbeans but in eclipse it still giving the error even by importing, i will look at it.

Comment: i tried in eclipse indigo and it works fine but in eclipse helio it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

User JSP usebean

```
<jsp:useBean id="test" class="testClass" /><%
test.testMethod();%>
```